# Bilinear functions

Tags: bilinear-form

I have some trouble with notation of bilinear functions. I will state the theorem i have trouble with:

A function $$\;\Bbb R^m\times \Bbb R^n\to\Bbb R\;$$ is bilinear if and only if it can be written in the form y=x1'Ax2 with A in Mmxn

Now, i will explain what i think is going on here. So I think what is meant with $$\;\Bbb R^m\times \Bbb R^n\to\Bbb R\;$$ is that a function whose domain is two arbitrarily vectors of dimension m and n respectively is mapped to a real number. For this to hold it should be possible to write it in y=x1'Ax2 where y is a real number x1' is a transposed vector and x2 is also a vector.

Now is this interpretation correct, that is, does $$\;\Bbb R^m\times \Bbb R^n\to\Bbb R\; $$represent any two arbitrary vectors as input, and is the output of this function a real number? Also, $$\;\Bbb R^m\times \Bbb R^n\;$$ specify nothing with respect to the vector being a column or row vector right?

If any of my interpretation is wrong please tell me, and possibly make things clearer for me.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I think it is $\;\Bbb R^m\times \Bbb R^n\to\Bbb R\;$ . Writing mathematics  properly in this site makes things much clearer many times. Read the following http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-qu%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8Bick-reference

Comment: But if we're talking of the **spaces** $\;\Bbb R^\,,\,\,\Bbb R^m\;$,  why do you *still* ask about these being "arbitrary vectors"?? The elements in $\;\Bbb R^m\times \Bbb R^n\;$ are of the form $\;(x,y)\;,\;\;x\in\Bbb R^m\;,\;\;y\in\Bbb R^n\;$ , and it doesn't really matter that much whether you consider $\;x,y,\;$ as row or column vectors, **until** you arrive at the $\;x^tAy\;$ part, with $\;A\;$ an $\;m\times n\;$ matrix, which then *forces* $\;x,y\;$ to be **column** vectors and thus $\;x^t\;$ is a row one.

Comment: I think im missing out on something here. Why wouldn't I talk of arbitrary vectors as the elements (x,y) are vectors right? So the input of this function would be any arbitrary pair of vectors mapped to a real number.

Comment: First, you wrote "..I think what is meant with $\;\Bbb R^m\times \Bbb R^n\to\Bbb R\;$ is that a function whose domain is two arbitrarily vectors of dimension m and n...", which of course is wrong: the domain is the product space $\;\Bbb R^m\times\Bbb R^n\;$  and this is what I firstly addressed. Second, the confusion between rown and column is addressed, too.

Comment: I think im confused about vector spaces then. I thought a vector space is a set which is closed under addition and scalar multiplication. In the case of the vector space $$\;\Bbb R^n\;$$ how is this any different from any arbitrary vector with dimension n. Thus the set of vectors with dimension n.

Comment: I think you're confused by what I'm trying to tell you wrt what **you** wrote. Nobody, as far as I can see, said *anything* about vector spaces not being closed under addition and stuff!

Comment: I see that, but can you tell me the difference between the set of vectors with dimension n and $$\;\Bbb R^n\;$$. I think that is still confusing me.

Comment: What is for you "a vector of dimension $\;n$"? Do you mean a vector of the form $\;(a_1,...,a_n)\;$ , with $\;a_i\;$ belonging to some field? Then there is an infinity of sets of vectors of this kind as there is an infinite of *different* fields. $\;\Bbb R^n\;$ is the vector space of all the vectors of the above form **when** $\;a_i\in\Bbb R\;$ .

Comment: yes i mean the set of vectors of the form $$\;(a_1,...,a_n)\;$$ with $$\;a_i\in\Bbb R\;$$. So this is the same as the vector space $$\;\Bbb R^n\;$$ right?

Comment: @jook Yes, it is the same.